# AutoCompleteTextView on Fragment without suggestions

Tags: android, android-fragments, autocompletetextview

I tried to implement following code to a fragment. Certainly I made all the necessary changes to avoid syntax and other errors.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

String[]dataStorage = {"Nigeria", "Ghana", "Mali", "South Africa", "Cameroon", "Niger", "Algeria", "Zimbabwe"};

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, dataStorage);

autoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(2);

autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

return true;

}

@Override

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will

// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long

// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

return true;

}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

It is running without any error, but I don't get search suggestions after first characters. First of all on-screen keyboard is opened in full view mode with a button called Submit. I can't get any suggestions or maybe I cannot see it because this full screen keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is merely the fullscreen keyboard hiding the search suggestions, you can disable the fullscreen keyboard by setting the `flagNoExtractUi` option:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" />
```

Apart from that, your code is fine, and the AutoCompleteTextView should work correctly.

Comment: I added this line to xml, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of you app when you typed some characters, plus the entire activity_main.xml?

Comment: It is in a `TableRow`, like below. Application screen looks really simple.
                    `<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
                        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                        android:ems="10">
                    <requestFocus />
                    </AutoCompleteTextView>
                </TableRow>`

Comment: So there is no dropdown box appearing at all if you enter for example "ni"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is my problem.

Comment: You write you are trying to implement the AutoCompleteTextView on a Fragment, but in your code there is only an Activity, no Fragment. How do you mean, implementing the AutoCompleteTextView on a Fragment?

Comment: `getView().findViewById` instead of `findViewById` and `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: You should post the exact code that you are using including the Activity and Fragment classes and the corresponding layout XMLs by editing your question.

Comment: Check it out here, please: https://gist.github.com/kovacsa91/b851c4a23a5411d578caccd86d915f9f

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation:

```
   setThreshold(int threshold)
```

Specifies the minimum number of characters the user has to type in the edit box before the drop down list is shown.

you are setting the threshold to 2 characters and then predict. Moreover, the list of test data supplied to the adapter is very unique

try setting the threshold to 0 and try again

also you should specify the type of the array adapter:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, dataStorage);
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, you also should specify the type of the arrayAdapter ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: can't find in you code anything else wrong, maybe the last thing is that "ActionBarActivity" is deprecated and you should use "AppCompatActivity"

Comment: also you could try the android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView with the AppCompatActivity

Comment: It is on a fragment in my application, so this isn't in use.

Comment: Full code is thousands of lines, but I pasted relevant code here. That is all about auto complete. XML file is pasted to another comment here.
https://gist.github.com/kovacsa91/54eb95f519f53f02bd318d4ed767c4e5